# Is overloading operator() for a reconstruction a good practice?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was thinking of the following scenario:

```
class A {
    private:

    std::string id;
    std::array<std::string, 128> data;

    public:

    A(const std::string& id) : id(id) {}
    A(const A& other) : id(other.id), data(other.data) {}
    virtual ~A(){}

    //to override the intern data
    A& operator=(const A& other) {

        this->data = other.data;

        return *this;
    }

    //to override the whole element
    A& operator()(const A& other) {

        this->id = other.id;
        this->data = other.data;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

As you can see, my idea was to use operator= to override the internal data and operator() to override the whole element. I was inspired by the constructor which would allow `A a(anOtherA);` to construct the element and I would like to override this for a re-construction. Now I don't now if this would be smart overloading this because it's actually the function call operator.

Comment: It would be better to give the function a name which makes its purpose clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Is overloading operator() for a reconstruction a good practice?

In short no, that isn't *good practice*. Such just obfuscates what is done under the hood.

Providing a setter for `data` and use the code you provided in your overloaded `operator()` for the implementation of the assignment `operator=()` would provide the clearer and naturally expected semantics:

```
class A {
    private:

    std::string id;
    std::array<std::string, 128> data;

    public:

    A(const std::string& id) : id(id) {}
    A(const A& other) : id(other.id), data(other.data) {}
    ~A(){}

    //to override the intern data
    A& operator=(const A& other) {
        id = other.id;
        data = other.data;

        return *this;
    }

    //to override the intern data
    void setData(const A& other) {
         data = other.data;
    }
    void setData(const std::array<std::string, 128>& data_) {
         data = data_;
    }
};
```

---

The semantics of the `operator()` isn't that clearly defined (vs the `operator=()`) beyond you can make a call of your class looking like a *"normal"* function call (which is mostly useful with templates taking your type as a parameter).
But I'd expect it more to do some *action* instead of changing the internal state of the class.

---

Regarding the style, instead of the `set` / `get` prefixes for getter/setter functions I prefer what's done in the c++ standard library, (like e.g. with the [`std::ios_base::flags()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) property):

```
class A {
private:
    // ...
    std::array<std::string, 128> data_;
public:
    const std::array<std::string, 128>& data() const {
         return data_;
    }
    void data(const std::array<std::string, 128>& data) {
         data_ = data;

    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: @tistCoder You may name the method as you want to make the semanitcs clear, but `override` is a c++ keywork, so be careful.

Comment: Well, I kind of forgot about it, don't ask how that could have happened... I'll use an other name

Comment: Actually, `override` is a context sensitive keyword. You can use it as an identifier.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, THX for that info. I'm still learning :)

Comment: Well, in that case i might use override() ;) Thanks for this information

Comment: @tistCoder I'm still not convinced of that naming. I'd probably reject that in a code review. Just try to be clear, not fancy ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Well, I actually thought the same but in my opinion override is a clear name and as long as the syntax allows this it shouldn't be a big problem. (It is a bad thought that all what the syntax allows is acceptable but in this case I'm sure of it)

Comment: @tistCoder I elaborated a bit more in my answer.  Anyhow that kind of _style_ questions is tending a bit to get opinions borderline.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's why I was asking for ;). I know there are many style things. For example the operator+() (without arguments) allows the std::ostream to print a char as number not as letter. In that case it is also not serving the standard functionality. It would actually say that a number is positive but math actually allows us to let it out.

Comment: @tistCoder Rule of thumb: Don't try to override operators with unexpected semantics. Besides that it doesn't pass (serious) code reviews, it just confuses others how to use your class API.

Comment: Don't worry I am NOT going to overload operators without a good background. In case of my question it was a background with multiple views so I was asking for the opinion of other people

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130631/discussion-between-tistcoder-and--).

Comment: @tistCoder Asking for opinions is _off-topic_ here, as you may already know. As mentioned your question is borderline regarding that, but can still be answered with showing clear and broadly accepted idioms that address your problem in c++. No need to chat, declined.

Comment: @tistCoder If you really want to, come over into the SOCVR chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34598079#34598079

Comment: @tistCoder At SOCVR, we can access a broader community deciding about the _borderline_ aspect I mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, but isn't such a long conversation between 2 persons inside the comment section unwelcome?

Comment: @tistCoder _"yes, but isn't such a long conversation between 2 persons inside the comment section unwelcome?"_ Yes. There are better chat rooms for that discussion though.

Answer (score 3):

great answer from πάντα ῥεῖ so please upvote that answer, not this one.

As you write, and more importantly, read more c++ you will come to appreciate people who name methods and functions with natural, meaningful names.

For most of us, if we see code like this:

```
X x;
Y y;

x(y);
```

We would think, before even looking at the declarations of `X` and `Y`, that `X` is some kind of function object (i.e. it does something) and `Y` is some kind of data or state object - it likes having things done to it, or it supplies data or services.

As a side note, a Haskell programmer would naturally assume that `Y` is also a function, but that's another story.

If your implementation of `X::operator()(Y)` does not "do X-type stuff with or to a Y" then it is probably inappropriately named.

If `Y` actually represents new state for `X`, and `X` intends to 'reset' itself using the data in `Y`, then the method should probably be called... `reset`:

```
X x;
Y y;

x.reset(y);  //ok, this is telling a better story
```

With reasonable names we can tell a narrative with our code:

```
void processResults(XFactory& factory, std::istream& is) {
    while(is) {
        auto x = X::createFrom(factory);
        x.collectNResults(is, 10);
        auto a = x.takeAverage();
        storeAverage(a);
        x.reset(y);
    }
}
```

Now even without looking up the definitions of the various classes I can get a sense of the general narrative. It's easier on the eye and I'm going to be able to hone in on the bits I need to see much more quickly than:

```
void processResults(XFactory& factory, std::istream& is) {
    while(is) {
        auto x = X(factory);
        x(is, 10);
        auto a = x();
        x(averageStore);
        x(y);
    }
}
```

Which is what I'd have if I wrote every operation on an X in terms of a call operator which, much like corporate tax avoidance, is actually perfectly legal, but nevertheless happens to upset other people because they end up paying the price for your selfishness.

Comment: _@Richard_ _"please upvote that answer, not this one."_ That's too decent, have an upvote ;P.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ aww you're too kind.